# Pycharm "mark as template" missing

Tags: python, django, windows, templates, pycharm

In my Pycharm I'm missing the 'templates' and 'resources' options for my directory folder. What should I fix in Pycharm to make this work?

[image: My_view]

[image: Menu]

[image: Suggestion]

Comment: Have you enabled django support in the project settings?

Comment: @IainShelvington There isn't an option to add django support for me, it might be because I'm using the community version and not the Pro. But Language/Frameworks doesn't have anything besides Schemas/DTDs and Restructured Tests. When I try to start a new project, there isn't an option to add a Django project, even when I know it's set up and installed module in Pycharm

Comment: Community edition lacks Django support and templates as well.